# SQLAPI++ in VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to use `SQLapi` library from inside Visual Studio 2012 x64 but `SQLapi` does not have lib & dll.

Of Visual Studio 2012 so I used older version from Visual Studio 2010 dll and lib.

First I got an error `msvcr100d.dll` not found (I think it is for Visual Studio 2010) even for Visual Studio 2010 x64.

Redistributal is installed, and I added to debug a folder manually, then I ran the program, I got another error.

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.

This may have been due to debug mode so I changed it to release mode but I got 22 linker errors what is wrong? I am not getting the exact problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clearly you'll need a VS2012 build of this DLL.  And you need a 64-bit version of it, the reason for the 0xc000007b error.  Contact the vendor or author for support.

Comment: yes i have write mail to sqlapi team well i am using trial version so i am not their high priority. but i hope they will reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved by SQLAPI team in newer version.